# How to select option by id or by name in Autocomplete Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I can't find solution how I can select same option by `id` and by `name` using Material-UI `Autocomplete`.

My array of options:

```
const options = [
   {id: 1, name: 'onion'},
   {id: 2, name: 'potato'},
   {id: 3, name: 'carrot'}
]
```

What I expect:

- If I type `3` I get option `carrot`
- I type `carrot` I get same option `carrot`

This is how my code is looking:

```
<Autocomplete
   classes={{
      root: classes.root
   }}
   style={{ padding: 0 }}
   options={options}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
   renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
         {...params}
         required
         className='inputPadding'
         classes={{ root: classes.labelRoot }}
         label={t('mainRank')}
         variant='outlined'
         helperText={positionObjErr && t('required')}
         error={positionObjErr}
      />
   )}
   getOptionSelected={(opt, val) => opt === val}
   value={positionObj}
   onChange={(e, val) => {
      val && setPositionObj(val)
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default `filterOptions` and make it filters by id after the label filter returns no result:

```js
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete, {
  createFilterOptions
} from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: "onion" },
  { id: 2, name: "potato" },
  { id: 3, name: "carrot" }
];
const _filterOptions = createFilterOptions();
const filterOptions = (options, state) => {
  const result = _filterOptions(options, state);

  if (result.length === 0) {
    return _filterOptions(options, {
      ...state,
      getOptionLabel: (o) => o.id.toString()
    });
  }

  return result;
};
```

#### Usage

```
export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66998083/how-to-select-option-by-id-or-by-name-in-autocomplete-material-ui]

Comment: Yes, this solutions works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition for the prop getOptionSelected like below so it will match for both string and id

```
<Autocomplete
   classes={{
      root: classes.root
   }}
   style={{ padding: 0 }}
   options={options}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
   renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
         {...params}
         required
         className='inputPadding'
         classes={{ root: classes.labelRoot }}
         label={t('mainRank')}
         variant='outlined'
         helperText={positionObjErr && t('required')}
         error={positionObjErr}
      />
   )}


   getOptionSelected={(opt, val) => opt.id === Number(val) || opt.name === val}


   value={positionObj}
   onChange={(e, val) => {
      val && setPositionObj(val)
   }}
/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, if I type `3` I get `No options`