# Updating the search function on Material UI's multiple values input component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik-material-ui

new to React and using Material UI's multiple values component to allow the user to select multiple options from the dropdown (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values). I want to update their implementation so that I can also search via year to return results, so finding 'The Godfather' for example could be found by searching '1972' as well. Does any one have any pointers on good places to start or helpful reading to implement this solution? Would really appreciate it!

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Tags() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 }
];
```

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66998083/9449426)